# Unable to install genymobile plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt, genymotion

Because the AVDs in ADT are too slow, I decided to install Genymotion. The installation of Genymotion was sucessful and I can also run an AVD there. Also my coded app in ADT Eclipse, I can run at Genymotion, strangely. 
The issue is, that I tried several times to install the plugin per "Help -> Install New Software..." and manually.
But I encounter this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,      
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing:      
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent,1.0.300.v20120912-130548
```

I dont know what that means. Can you help me?

Thx in Advance!

With best regards,
HaoRyan

Answer (score 0):

What's your version of genymotion?
It seems that u can already debug with Genymotion in Eclipse?